# How to save Facebook and Skype information to Google contacts?

Tags: facebook, skype, google-contacts

I've looked around this site and in spite of what I read I can't figure out the following:

**How do I save my merged contact information into a Google contact?**

For instance, I have a friend F who has a phone number Fp a mail address Fm, a Skype username Fs and and Facebook username Ff. Although these data are merged into a single F contact on android, I cannot see Fs and Ff in F's Google contact.

How can I really merge the data so it all shows into Google accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, as far as Facebook you need to use an external agent. Here is what I mean:

Because Facebook does not work with Google very well you have to sign up for Yahoo! Mail. 
In the contacts option you will be able to import your contacts from Facebook. Once you do that you can then export them as a spreadsheet and then once again import them into Google Contacts using the import feature.

Skype would be different as you would have to class their Skype username as a note rather than a phone number or email, you would have to do that manually.

Comment: Thanks. It seems though the answer should be "No you can't but there is a workaround..."   Do I understand you well saying the issue is a kind of embargo on Facebook and Skype by Google? If so are there alternate, third-party, contact databases I could use, which would collect **all** contact information?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I did some more research and it turns out that although not listed, Google Contacts would let you add your friends skype name under the "Internet Call" category. Interestingly you are also able to create your own category which you could name "Skype" if you wish. These can be found once you click the "Add" button on your contact. You will still however have to add your Skype details manually. Hope this helps :)

Comment: No, Google doesn't have an embargo, _facebook_ has an embargo, and makes it nearly impossible to extract friend's data. (Same with skype, but I think that's just poor desgin on skype's part).  The data that can be extracted, yahoo makes it easier than any other service.